# Ubuntu Server Custom Port for SSH

Tags: ssh, ubuntu

I've defined a custom port for SSH within `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on my ubuntu-server installation and it is still accepting SSH on port 22 after rebooting the server.

Is there something else I need to do other than....

```
Host *

PermitRootLogin no

   Port 6685
   Protocol 2,1
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: As Zoredache said, that is the file you need to edit but dont forget to restart the ssh service aswell

Comment: Thought he had said he rebooted the server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The configuration you are looking for is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  The ssh_config file is for the ssh client.